# Weird UITextView behavior (Snaphotting exception)

Tags: ios, swift

So there's an app where I have 2 text views in a stack view, one for input and the other one for output (much like Google Translate app).

I constrained the stack view to leading and trailing edges of the view and to the top of the safeAreaLayoutGuide (since I have my VC inside a navigation controller). I also initially gave my text views the height of 150 points.

outputTextView is initially hidden and only when I put text into inputTextView I animate isHidden property of outputTextView. The same goes when inputTextView is empty so I hide outputTextView:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView == inputTextView {
            if textView.hasText {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    self.outputTextView.isHidden = false
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
                    self.outputTextView.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my inputTextView I implemented a placeholder logic: I gave it a default text "Some text" with a light gray color and then in didBeginEditing and didEndEditing delegate methods I implemented the following logic:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView == inputTextView && textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Some text"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
```

There are currently 2 issues I can't figure my head over:

1. Firstly, when my inputTextView have the height of 150 everything works fine but when I change its height to, say, 100 points, I get the following:
   [image: inputTextView]

I **solved the issue by calling layoutIfNeeded()** on inputTextView after setting all the stack view's constraints. But I'm not exactly sure why I need to do this so I hope someone will be able to clarify that for me.

2. The second issue is the following: after several cycles of inputting-erasing text inside inputTextView, the **"placeholder" text seems to shift downwards** a couple of points:

[image: placeholder]

In addition to that, when I select my inputTextField I get this sporadic exception: **[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7ff43b538ce0, UIInputSetContainerView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.**

It's pretty hard to catch it, sometimes it happens without putting any text into textview, sometimes after several cycles of inputting-erasing, but the only thing that is always true is that it happens **when you select the textView**. I tried to put some layoutIfNeeded() here and there but this didn't fix the issues.

Comment: Your way of handling a placeholder is likely the cause. You maybe should use a UILabel and keep it separate instead of using text on the UITextView. The brief moment that there is no text is likely causing constraint issues as well. Do you have scrolling disabled?

Comment: @agibson007 Thanks for the suggestion with the separate label, I'll try it if everything else fails. As for scrolling, I had it enabled but disabling it has no effect whatsoever.